# what is default in react import

Tags: reactjs

I am going through some react code, can any one please let me know what does **default as React** in below code does.

```
import {
  default as React,
  Component,
  PropTypes,
} from "react";
```

Thanks,
Guru

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is default in react import?

Default in that context is the entire `React` library.  It is unnecessary in this case and could be shortened to `import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Another thing to note, is that `proptypes` have been moved to their own [package](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) now.

Answer (score 0):

That's the same as:

```
import React, { Component, Proptype } from 'react';
```

obs: Since react v15.5 React.PropTypes has moved into [a different package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)